# 404 | Not found - Tras crear middleware para roles de usuario en Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tras crear **middleware** para roles de usuario, un controlador que antes no daba problemas, ahora devuelve Error404. ¿Qué puede haber sucedido? He colocado en dd($categoria) para ver si llega el parámetro y no llega ni el parámetro. Otros controladores sí funcionan sin problema.

Enlace:

```
<a class="portfolio-link" href="{{url('/preguntas/intro')}}">
```

Controlador:

```
    Route::any('/preguntas/{categoria}',
'PreguntaController@show');
```

PreguntaController.php:

```
public function show($categoria)
    { 
dd($categoria);
}
```

Por ejemplo tengo otra ruta al mismo controlador, esta vez al index, y funciona perfecto:

```
Route::resource('/preguntas','PreguntaController');
```

Comment: no es el modo en la ruta del enlace''

Comment: Antes de crear los roles, funcionaba bien. De todos modos, ¿Cómo debería ser la ruta?

Comment: Usas la version mas nueva de laravel?

Comment: Así es. uso la versión más nueva de Laravel. Creo que el error está en cómo tengo el enlace con parámetro en el <a href=""> ¿Cómo sería? Un saludo.

Comment: Tendrías que quitar la parte del ´`/intro´` ya que esta buscando esa pagina y tu le estas pasando un parametro ´`categoria`´

Comment: si vas a pasar un parametro a tu vista show, deberias de hacerlo por ejemplo desde un index o alguna pagina ejemplo `{{ url('/admin/categories/'.$category->id.'/edit') }}`